# Композиция бинарных отношений (на матрице) равна произведению матриц бинарных отношений?

Tags: математика, дискретная-математика

Композиция бинарных отношений (на матрице) равна произведению матриц бинарных отношений?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, является.

Только перемножать матрицы нужно логически, то есть вместо умножения должно быть **И**, вместо сложения **ИЛИ**.

Цитата из учебница по дискретной математике:

> Матрица композиции двух отношений равна логическому произведению
>   матриц исходных отношений.

Это, кстати, имеет простое объяснение. Произведение матриц в алгебраическом смысле даёт число двузвенных путей в соответствующем графе между соответствующими вершинами, если путей больше нуля - значит эти две вершины соотносятся в смысле **композиции отношений** (см. определение композиции, оно ровно так и определяется). Термы матричного произведения будут 1-цами, если есть соответствующий, если есть хоть один путь - операция или между несколькими термами, среди которых есть хоть одна 1-ца даст как раз единицу.

Это расплывчатое объяснение, более подробно можно найти в любой книге по дискретной математике.